# Groupby Column in Pandas and Perform calculation (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to:

1. **Take the average of the TotalB column based upon grouping the TotalB column**.
2. I would then like to **take this new column and subtract the free value to obtain the Used value**

df1

```
date        name    rack    TotalB  freeB   
11/20/2020  a       yes     11      5   
11/20/2020  a       yes     10      5   
11/20/2020  a       yes     12      5   
11/20/2020  a       yes     10      5   
11/20/2020  b       no      5       2   
11/20/2020  b       no      5       2   
11/20/2020  b       no      6       2
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
date        name    rack    TotalB  freeB   UsedB
11/20/2020  a       yes     10.75       5    5.75
11/20/2020  b       no      5.33        2    3.33
```

**What I am doing:**

```
df.groupby('rack')['TotalB'].mean()
UsedB = df["TotalB"] - df["freeB"]
```

I am having trouble with retaining all the columns within the dataset.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the question, it seems like you want to do something like the following:

```
df = df1.groupby(['date', 'name', 'rack'], as_index=False).agg({'TotalB': 'mean', 'freeB': 'mean})
```

which will group by the first 3 columns, and find the mean of the last 2, followed by

```
df['UsedB'] = df.TotalB - df.freeB
```

Answer (score 1):

Groupby similar columns, calculate the mean then assign UsedB

`df.groupby(['date', 'name', 'rack', 'freeB']).agg({'TotalB': 'mean'}).reset_index().assign(UsedB=lambda x: x['TotalB'] - x['freeB'])`

```
         date name rack  freeB     TotalB     UsedB
0  11/20/2020    a  yes      5  10.750000  5.750000
1  11/20/2020    b   no      2   5.333333  3.333333
```

You could also use the `as_index=False` option:

```
df.groupby(["date", "name", "rack"], as_index=False).mean().assign(
    UsedB=lambda x: x.TotalB - x.freeB
)
```